# Craft 2.2 with enabled enableCsrfProtection: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: error-message, upload

Since the update to version 2.2 I can't upload assets.

I get this error message in the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

And the upload stops:
[image: upload error]

Any idea why?

Comment: Anything relevant getting logged in your craft/storage/runtime/logs files?  You can search for [error] and [warning].

Comment: Found this error in the logfile: "2014/09/04 06:21:06 [error] [exception.CHttpException.400] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The CSRF token could not be verified.' in /home/netsh107500/html/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1247"

Comment: I don't know why because the Cookie is set: CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN aebf01121550bc05e312fd6f1b628b07fde5db3bs%3A40%3A%22ed2516a95487688aafbbaa57c709811e87b79bfc%22%3B dev.local / Session 114 B ✓

Comment: When I set enableCsrfProtection to false the upload works.

Comment: Everything else with enableCsrfProtection enabled works fine (forms in frontend and backend editing).

Comment: Hey guys, I'm having this same issue. <h2>Bad Request</h2><p>The CSRF token could not be verified.</p>[error] [exception.CHttpException.400] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The CSRF token could not be verified.' in */craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1247

Comment: This should be fixed in [Craft 2.2.2582](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2582).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug on [Craft 2.2.2579](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/csrf-protection) when CSRF protection is enabled.  Will get a fix out for it shortly and update this answer when it's done.

**Update**:

Fixed in [Craft 2.2.2582](https://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2582).